# Finding the probability that a sum of normal variables does not exceed a certain treshold

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question about a relatively simple probability exercise involving a sum of components. It goes as follows:

> A cargo ship has a maximum payload of $50,000$ kilograms. The ship is loaded    with boxes of rice, that each have a mean weight of $50$ kilograms and a standard deviation of $5$ kilograms.
>
> How many boxes can be loaded onto the ship, so that the odds of the maximum payload being exceeded is smaller than or equal to $0.001$?

I thought that if each box $X$ was distributed as

$$X \sim \mathcal{N} ( 50,5^2)$$

the sum $S$ of the boxes would be distributed as

$$S\sim \mathcal{N} ( n\cdot 50, n\cdot 5^2)$$

so that the solution to the question would be
$$P(S \leq 50 000) = 0.999.$$

$$P\left(Z \leq\frac{50 000 - n⋅50}{5 \cdot \sqrt{n}} \right) = 0.999$$

$$\frac{50 000 - n\cdot 50}{5 \cdot \sqrt{n}}= 2.97$$

If I solve it this way, I get two complex solutions. According to the solutions manual, the answer should be $990$. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, it seems you just didn't solve the quadratic equation properly. We have
$$
n^2 - 2000.088209n + 1000000 = 0
$$
with roots $n=990.652$, $n=1009.436$. It is clear that the second root is not a suitable solution, so we round down the first root to get $990$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Your assumption that the weight of each box is normally distributed is unnecessary.  Use the Central Limit Theorem instead.